# Deserialize Json into List<long> fails

Tags: c#, json, serialization

In my ASP.Net Core 3.1 application, I have the following json string:

```
   string body = "{\"idsModel\":{\"IdsToDraft\":[792,793,794]}}";
```

And here is my POCO I'm trying to deserialize that string into:

```
public class IdsModel
    {
        public List<long> IdsToDraft { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my deserialization code:

```
idsModel = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IdsModel>(body);
```

At the end of this, the `idsModel` object is created, but the `IDsToDraft` property of the object is null.

I've tried both the Newtonsoft and the .Net Core System.Text.Json serializers.

I've tried different combinations of casing in the source string.

Why is that?  Why is the List property not being deserialized?!?

Comment: Looking at the json, you need a class that has  a property named idsModel, which is a class having property of type int[] named IdsToDraft

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ you sure about that?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Yes, because it is perfectly valid JSON.

Comment: @Cid I'm guessing he's never heard of escaping special characters

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ because you're leaving in the escape characters for the quotation marks which get parsed out of the string in C#, or any programming language. Google "escaping special characters in C#".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the root object, the one that contains `idsModel` :

```
public class RootClass
{
    public IdsModel IdsModel { get; set; }
}

public class IdsModel
{
    public List<long> IdsToDraft { get; set; }
}

// ...

var idsModel = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootClass>(body);
```

Answer (score 1):

The model should look like

```
public class IdsModel
{
    public List<long> IdsToDraft { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public IdsModel idsModel { get; set; }
}
```